# ftpUpload() failure:<not set> under strange circumstances in R

Tags: r, ftp

My computer runs an R script automatically every ten minutes processing data tables and then uploading 8 output files. Introducing a 9th file returns an error `<not set>`.

At the end of the main script, a subscript is called on:

```
upload()
```

### which is

```
library(RCurl)
upload<-function(){
    allFiles<-
    c('f1.csv','f2.csv','f3.png','f4.png','f5.png', 
    'f6.png','f7.png','f8.png')
    nFiles<-length(allFiles)
    for (n in allFiles)
    ftpUpload(n,paste("ftp://USER:PASS@//DOMAIN//DIR1//",n,sep=''))
    }
```

Now, when i want to add more files to `allFiles` the program returns this error:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : <not set>
Calls: upload ... ftpUpload -> curlPerform -> .Call -> <Anonymous> -> fun
Execution halted
```

Then I try to manually execute the upload

```
allFiles<-
c('f1.csv','f2.csv','f3.png','f4.png','f5.png', 
'f6.png','f7.png','f8.png', 'ADDED_FILE.png')
nFiles<-length(allFiles)
for (n in allFiles)
ftpUpload(n,paste("ftp://USER:PASS@//DOMAIN//DIR1//",n,sep=''))
```

Which returns the same error

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : <not set>
```

If I remove the added file and the rerun the function, R still returns the `<not set>` error

The only way to get around it is to uninstall "RCurl", restart program R, and then reinstall "RCurl".

Having a separate dedicated ftpUpload() in the upload() function as well as putting it in a completely other script still returns the `<not set>` error.

any ideas on what is happening?